# Postfix aliases and duplicate e-mails, how to fix?

Tags: email, mac-osx, postfix, osx-snow-leopard

I have aliases set up in postfix, such as the following:

```
all@mydomain.com:    foo@mydomain.com, bar@mydomain.com ...
```

When an email is sent to all@mydomain.com, and any of the recipients in that alias is cc:ed which is quite common (ie: "Reply all"), the e-mail is delivered in duplicates. For instance, if an e-mail is sent to all@mydomain.com and foo@mydomain.com is cc:ed, it'll get delivered twice. According to the [Postfix FAQ](http://www.postfix.org/faq.html#duplicate), this is by design as Postfix sends e-mail in parallel without expanding the groups, which makes it faster than sendmail. Now that's all fine and dandy, but is it possible to configure Postfix to actually remove duplicate recipients before sending the e-mail?

I've found a lot of posts from people all over the net that has the same problem, but I have yet to find an answer. If this is not possible to do in Postfix, is it possible to do it somewhere on the way? I've tried educating my users, but it's rather futile I'm afraid...

I'm running postfix on Mac OS X Server 10.6, amavis is set as content_filter and dovecot is set as mailbox_command. I've tried setting up procmail as a content_filter for smtp delivery (as per the suggestion below), but I can't seem to get it right. For various reasons, I can't replace the standard OS X configuration, meaning postfix, amavis and dovecot stay put. I can however add to it if I wish.

Comment: I think it's really just not possible...

Comment: I'm truly starting to believe that you are right Antoine.

Comment: Well that was a waste of a bounty...

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way how to do it, but not using Postfix itself.

If you are using a reasonably recent Dovecot with **Pigeonhole implementation of Sieve**, there is a special extension that can be used for on-delivery deduplication. In Dovecot older than 2.2.18, the name of this *extension is "vnd.dovecot.duplicate"* and it's disabled by default, in newer releases the *extension is called "duplicate"* and should be already enabled, but enabling it explicitly won't harm.

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf:**

```
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve

  sieve_before = /mnt/mail/users/global_sieve/deduplicate.sieve
  # sieve_before2 = /mnt/mail/users/global_sieve/antispam.sieve

  sieve_extensions = +vnd.dovecot.duplicate  # for dovecot < 2.2.18
  #sieve_extensions = +duplicate             # for dovecot >= 2.2.18
}
```

Then create the sieve script to handle the deduplication itself (you can adjust the filename as you see fit).

**/mnt/mail/users/global_sieve/deduplicate.sieve:**

```
require "vnd.dovecot.duplicate"; # for dovecot < 2.2.18
# require "duplicate";           # for dovecot >= 2.2.18

if duplicate {
    discard;
    stop;
}
```

Compile the script using *sievec* and make sure the script is readable by *dovecot* user. [More in Dovecot docs.](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Extensions/Duplicate)

If you are using Cyrus, there is a a [duplicate message delivery suppression](http://www.cyrusimap.org/~vanmeeuwen/imap/features/duplicate-message-delivery-suppression.html) feature that can be enabled using `suppress_duplicates = yes`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing this mechanism out. That "finding a needle in a haystack" feeling.

Comment: Discoveries during implementation: `duplicate` extension works at user level. I was trying to stop duplicates over multiple users To/Cc-d in a central `fileinto` mailbox. This doesn't work. Had to also set a postfix `virtual_alias_maps` catch-all entry, such as `@domain.com catchall@domain.com`, then the sieve duplicate check will hit `catchall` user's duplicate list.

Comment: Yeah, that's very similar to "finding a needle in a haystack" feeling

Comment: Thank you! This answer works for me. I setup 2 aliases, each one of them, has the same members. And then, I sent from myemail@gmail.com to the 2 aliases at the same time and I only received 1 message at each of the alias member inbox.

Before I always got 2 copies at each alias member inbox.

Answer (score 5):

Postfix has no idea about duplicate emails due to the way it's structured. It is possible to do what you're suggesting by using procmail as your delivery agent.

Essentially, each message coming from a client should be delivered with a unique Message-Id. In the case that it's delivered to multiple people, the Message-Id should be the same, so we save any `Message-Id` headers we've seen and discard and future ones that match that list.

From http://novosial.org/procmail/

```
:0 Wh: msgid.lock
| formail -D 8192 ~/.procmail/msgid.cache
```

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, it isn't possible to solve in Postfix because Postfix sends the e-mails in parallel, ie it sends to foo@mydomain.com at the same time as it expands all@mydomain.com and then again sends to foo@mydomain.com.

Wouldn't the Procmail solution then possibly introduce a race condition where another unrelated e-mail (with a different message id) is sent in between the two e-mails in question and thus overwriting the cache making it so that duplicate e-mails are delivered anyhow?

Comment: I'm trying to get your suggestion to work, but I'm not really sure how to combine this with dovecot delivery, which is used by OS X 10.5+ by default.

Comment: If you're using dovecot as a delivery agent, you can use procmail as a `content_filter` which will allow you to perform the same task on a global level

Comment: I have to confess that I probably am in way over my head here. I've been staring myself blind on the configuration parameters page for postfix and googling till my fingers bleed but I can't seem to figure out how to configure this. Any resources you might know of or nudges in the right direction would really be appreciated!

Comment: I think I sort of understand how it works now, but there's already a content_filter set to amavis. This seems to be some sort of anti virus checker. I've read that it's possible to chain content_filters, but it seems rather unintuitive and the documentation is less than stellar. It's really quite ridiculous how difficult it is to just weed out duplicate e-mails. Design desicions regardless, this seems to me like it should be in there out of the box or at least not require these monstruos hacks.

Comment: On Ubuntu 8.04 this solution worked perfectly for me with some minor adjustments.  Each email user has a home directory which has a `.procmailrc` that is a sym link to a central file under /etc.  This file contains the procmail recipe in the answer adjusted as follows: `| /usr/bin/formail -D 8192 $PMDIR/msgid.cache` where `$PMDIR` was previously defined in the system procmail file as `$HOME/procmail`.  Put the users' .procmailrc and the procmail directory in the /etc/skel directory to ensure new user accounts get this set up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that work for me is add `-o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings` on `master.cf`

Here the doc: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#receive_override_options

Comment: Hi @Pioz, thanks for your answer, I visited the official doc and I have not yet fully understand, because after I set this option on my master.cf, postfix starts ignoring aliases set in Goto column in virtual alias table. Is this settings was supposed to turn off alias / forwarding feature of postfix?

Answer (score 0):

This is from some old postfix faq:

Postfix sends duplicate mail
Some people will complain that Postfix sends duplicate messages. This happens whenever one message is mailed to multiple addresses that reach the same user. Examples of such scenarios are:

> - One message is sent to the user, and to an alias that lists the user. The
>     user receives one copy of the mail
>     directly, and one copy via the alias.
>
>   - One message is sent to multiple aliases that list the user. The user
>       receives one copy of the mail via each
>       alias.
>
> Some people will even argue that this
>   is the "right" behavior. It is
>   probably more a matter of expectation
>   and of what one is used to.
>
> This can be "fixed" only by making
>   Postfix slower. In the above examples,
>   Postfix would first have to completely
>   expand all distribution lists before
>   starting any delivery. By design,
>   Postfix delivers mail to different
>   destinations in parallel, and local
>   delivery is no exception. This is why
>   Postfix can be faster than sendmail.

So by design you are seeing that behavior.  Perhaps if you find a content filter that can strip duplicate message IDs, you can eliminate this after the delivery event.

Sendmail does not have this problem because it expands everything first and strips out duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I read that, perhaps I should have updated my question. By design or not, it's still an issue. I understand why it's behaving the way it does and I understand that trying to find a solution in Postfix is futile. However, I've tried coming up with some content filter solution using Procmail and I just can't seem to get it right. It's highly likely that I'm not understanding content filters or procmail correctly, or both. In either case I still would like to fix this. Unfortunately, the setup as it is cannot be modified, only added to. I can't use sendmail instead of postfix, unfortunately.

Comment: I updated the question with some more information but honestly, the link to the FAQ was in there to start with. I do appreciate any helpful suggestions though!

Comment: Did not realize that was a link to the same content. Working in IT security, you become rather paranoid about clicking random links.

Can  you confirm that the duplicate messages have the same message IDs?

Comment: Been a long day so I need to review your original post but what about this:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#duplicate_filter_limit

Comment: I can indeed confirm that the duplicate messages have the same message IDs. Setting the duplicate_filter_limit does nothing to help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The oficial solution is here.. http://osdir.com/ml/mail.postfix.devel/2007-05/msg00010.html

duplicate_filter_limit (10000)
The maximal number of addresses remembered by the recipient
duplicate filters for aliases(5) or virtual(5) alias expansion,
or for showq(8) queue displays (with earlier Postfix releases
the default limit was 1000).

duplicate_filter_style (strict)
The duplicate recipient filter policy: strict or pragmatic.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/postfix-nodup-daemon-configuration-td40410.html claims this was never implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
enable_original_recipient=no
```

I put that in my main.cf and it worked fine but only for mail sent from my domain. I still have duplicates if I send email from outside my domain (yahoo to my domain for eg.)

source : http://article.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/119783

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried using the `pigeonhole (sieve)` approach but it resulted more complicated for such a minor feature (prevent duplicates when storing and forwarding at the same time). I also tried most of the suggestions here without success (is not that they are mistaken, they just didn't work for me).

One way to solve this is to clearly identify aliases vs mailboxes. If you are using emails as usernames, I guess you need to adjust this method. In my case, user accounts are like: `user1000` for the email  `user@example.com`. This is how to solve it:

1. In the configuration where you get the directory path for the user (e.g. `mysql.users.cf`), you have to be sure to use mailbox accounts only (not email addresses) to search:

```sql
SELECT home_dir FROM accounts WHERE CONCAT(username, '@', 'mail.example.com')='%s'
```

It should return the full path to the inbox if exists, or nothing if the username doesn't exists or is just an alias for another email (account without mailbox). You can test with this command:

```
postmap -q 'user1000@mail.example.com' mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql.users.cf
```

(please note that we use `user1000@mail.example.com` and not `user@example.com`)

**NOTE**: `mail.example.com` is the FQDN of your mail server and it is used to identify mailboxes from incoming emails and external accounts. You can not use your domain (e.g. example.com) here as postfix won't be able to tell the difference between incoming emails and forwarded ones (resulting in duplicate emails). You could use `localhost` instead, but postfix will complain as `@localhost` is used mainly for OS physical accounts.

2. In the alias configuration file (e.g. `mysql.aliases.cf`), return the addresses you want to store or forward to:

```sql
SELECT address FROM aliases WHERE email='%s'
```

You can return a list of addresses (one by line) or a single line separated by comma. You can test with this command:

```
postmap -q 'user@example.com' mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql.aliases.cf
```

Now, the trick here is that you **must** return only email addresses , do not return account names here, instead append your server FQDN
as explained above. For example, the previous SQL should return something like (the order is not important):

```
SELECT address FROM aliases WHERE email='info@example.com'

sam_t100@yahoo.com   <-- external
peter123@mail.example.com  <-- internal/local
info4562@mail.example.com  <-- internal/local
root@mail.example.com      <-- internal/local
rose@gmail.com      <-- external
```

(note that we are returning local mailboxes as `*@mail.example.com` as explained above)

In this way, postfix can clearly identify what should be stored and what should be forwarded and duplicates emails are no more.